# Why is one of these functions changing the original array and not the other?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm not sure what I am missing by looking at these three functions.
The desired result for these functions would be that the original array changes value so

```
change_this = [6, 7, 8]
array_times_two!(change_this)
change_this == [12, 14, 16] => true
```

The following function does this

```
def array_times_two!(array)
  array.map! {|x| x * 2}
end
```

And so does this one...

```
def array_times_two!(array)
  array.each_with_index do |element, index|
    array[index] = array[index] * 2
  end
  array
end
```

How come the following function does not change the value like the others?

```
def array_times_two!(array)
  array = array.map {|x| x * 2}
  array
end
```

How is the second function changing the array but the third isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last example you have `array` coming in as a local variable. Reassigning the local variable has zero effect on the original variable. This is because Ruby is, in effect, pass by value, except the confusing part is those values are often *object references*, or a fancy term for pointers.

The consequences of this aren't that complicated though: Calling a method on an object *can* modify the contents of that object. Reassigning a variable cannot.

The first version of your method is probably the best, but you could make it more generic, like:

```
def multiply_by!(array, n = 2)
  array.map! { |v| v * n }
end
```

You can also "fix" the last version by using a method call to apply the changes:

```
def array_times_two!(array)
  array.replace(array.map {|x| x * 2})
end
```

This calls `Array#replace` to stomp the contents of the original object and force the changes to stick. It's not a very elegant solution when things like `map!` exist.